# Android: how to access objects stored with FileOutputStream

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I am able to store objects to an android device, but I'm having trouble retrieving them. Data within these objects is set by the user (ie String name, int day, ect). These objects are stored (with their key being their name)  and later in a different activity they're supposed to be retrieved. I can't retrieve them because in the new activity I don't their name for it is determined by the user.

To store objects (object=person)

```
  FileOutputStream fStream = context.openFileOutput(name,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  ObjectOutputStream oStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fStream);
  oStream.writeObject(person);
  oStream.close();
  fStream.close();
```

To retrieve objects (done in a different class)

```
  FileInputStream fStream = context.openFileInput( //where the name of the object should be, here's where I'm stuck );
  ObjectInputStream oStream = new ObjectInputStream(fStream);
  person = oStream.readObject();
```

Since I'm in a new activity, I have no idea what the user had predetermined their name to be. I can't simply just name the key "person" in both because the user is making an undetermined amount of people and is constantly adding and deleting people. If there was a way to just count the amount of stored objects, or get a list of all the stored objects' names, my problem would be solved.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to go about it. You can keep track of the names and then passed them in a Bundle to your new activity or you can use @longwalker's code below but change the first line to retrieve the internal files directory as that is where your files are being saved. So you should use getFilesDir(). See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()

Comment: Or just use fileList(). See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#fileList()

Comment: Leco's comments solved my problem! thanks man

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are trying to get the list the files from a certain directory. You can do so this way:

```
// Get local files
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + localDir);

File[] listOfLocalFilesArray = directory.listFiles();

// get the names of files
String[] fileArray = new String[listOfLocalFilesArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < listOfLocalFilesArray.length; i++) {
 fileArray[i] = listOfLocalFilesArray[i].getName();
}
```

Comment: what would I put for localDir?

Comment: Whatever the directory was when you stored the files!  If you stored the files in the external storage root directory, then just use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()`.

Comment: Understood, might I ask if you would know what the directory of the stored "person" objects would be? as of now, if I print out fileArray, I get "Android, Music, Podcasts, ..., DCIM". Thanks for all the help so far by the way!